# Splash screen Error "Application is not a member of My"

Tags: vb.net

i am getting this error when i try to run my application "Application is not a member of My", i recently added a splash screen, this error is coming from the code below. i have tried running devenv.exe/resetsetting from command prompt to enable Application framework and its not work. anyone with a simpler method of resolving this will be appreciated

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Public NotInheritable Class SplashScreen1

'TODO: This form can easily be set as the splash screen 
'      for the application by going to the "Application" tab
'      of the Project Designer ("Properties" under the "Project" menu).

Private Sub SplashScreen1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
    Handles Me.Load

    'Set up the dialog text at runtime according to
    'the application's assembly information.  

    'TODO: Customize the application's assembly information 
    '      in the "Application" pane of the project 
    '      properties dialog (under the "Project" menu).

    'Application title

    If True Then
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(My.Application.Info.Title) Then
            ApplicationTitle.Text = My.Application.Info.Title
        Else
            'If the application title is missing, 
            'use the application name without the extension
            ApplicationTitle.Text = _
                System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(My.Application.Info.AssemblyName)
        End If

        'Format the version information using the 
        'text set into the Version control at design time as the
        'formatting string. This allows for effective localization if desired.
        'Build and revision information could be included by 
        'using the following code and changing the version control's designtime 
        'text to "Version {0}.{1:00}.{2}.{3}" or something similar.  
        'See String.Format() in Help for more information.
        '
        'Version.Text = System.String.Format(Version.Text, _
        '                                    My.Application.Info.Version.Major, _
        '                                    My.Application.Info.Version.Minor, _
        '                                    My.Application.Info.Version.Build, _
        '                                    My.Application.Info.Version.Revision)

        Version.Text = System.[String].Format(Version.Text, _
                                              My.Application.Info.Version.Major, _
                                              My.Application.Info.Version.Minor)

        'Copyright info
        Copyright.Text = My.Application.Info.Copyright

    End If

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Have you tried removing "My"?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's the use of `If True Then`?

Answer (score 1):

In your Project Properties try to set your Startup form to your Main Form and the click enable application framework. Then you should be able to set the SplashScreen as your splash screen. Confirm that you have code as follows:

```
Private Sub SplashScreen1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'Set up the dialog text at runtime according to the application's assembly information.  

    'TODO: Customize the application's assembly information in the "Application" pane of the project 
    '  properties dialog (under the "Project" menu).

    'Application title
    If My.Application.Info.Title <> "" Then
        ApplicationTitle.Text = My.Application.Info.Title
    Else
        'If the application title is missing, use the application name, without the extension
        ApplicationTitle.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(My.Application.Info.AssemblyName)
    End If

    Version.Text = System.String.Format(Version.Text, My.Application.Info.Version.Major, My.Application.Info.Version.Minor)

    'Copyright info
    Copyright.Text = My.Application.Info.Copyright
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you everyone for effort to help, i solved this by opening project.vbproj file with notepad and edited:  <MyType>Empty</MyType> to <MyType>WindowsForm</MyType>

Answer (score 0):

On my project, in case someone is interested, it worked by opening the project.vbproj file and changing:

```
<MyType>Empty</MyType>
```

to

```
<MyType>Windows</MyType>
```

instead of 'WindowsForms'