# 'Application' is not a member of 'My'

Tags: vb.net, member

I'm trying to add a Splash Screen to my form, but I'm getting the error -

> 'Application' is not a member of 'My'.

I've done some research and came across two possible solutions, but neither of them have worked for me.

1. **[Splash Screen Error "'Application' is not a member of 'My'."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483583/splash-screen-error-application-is-not-a-member-of-my)** The answer here suggests ticking the 'Enable Application Framework' option in the Project settings, but that option is greyed out.
2. **[The 'My' Namespace in a VB.NET Application is Missing Members.](http://allen-conway-dotnet.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/my-namespace-in-vbnet-application-is.html)** This answer suggests that I need to add a Reference to the Project in the Project settings, but doing this does not fix the error.

Can anyone please suggest what I can do to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a known issue for me. Open .vbproj file  and change where it says

```
<MyType>Empty</MyType>
```

to

```
<MyType>WindowsForm</MyType>
```

Answer (score 3):

We tried the suggestion above but it did not work for us with a Class Library in Visual Studio 2013.
After investigating another project that worked, we found that changing to using "Windows" instead of "WindowsForm" enabled that functionality

```
<MyType>Windows</MyType>
```

Comment: Why was this correct solution for certain file types voted down?

Comment: In my case my VS 2008 had 2 projects where one project had "Custom" between the <MyType/> tags (the other .vbproj already had "Windows").  Changing from Custom to Windows worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this issue as well.  The solution in my case was that I had created a .NET Core app, rather than a .NET Framework app.

Copied my code into a new Framework app and it worked just fine.